# Email HTML - Making a responsive background image for a table

Tags: html, css, email, background-image, html-email

I've used http://backgrounds.cm to make a background image for my table, and I'm going through the horrid process of making an email campaign which requires writing HTML that looks like it's very, very old.

Anyway here's my code for the table:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="force-row" style="width: 600px;" background="images/image.png" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="bottom">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:576px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="images/merrychristmas.png" color="#ffffff" />
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <tr>
    <td class="cols-wrapper" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px">
    <!--[if mso]>
      <table border="0" width="576" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 576px;">
      <tr><td width="576" style="width: 576px;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
        <table width="576" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row" style="width: 576px;">
          <tr>
            <td class="col" valign="top" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px">
              <div class="col-copy" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;color:#333333;margin-top:12px">Content here</div>
              <br>
              <table bgcolor="#1480ef" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="button" height="35" style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;padding:0 20px 0 20px;">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;">Button</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr><!-- /Content -->
        </table>
      <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</table>
```

The background image appears fine that I am using, but as I'm trying to create a responsive Email design, it doesn't scale properly. I have a banner near the top which scales perfectly fine, but I don't know how to make the background image scale. The image stays a fixed width at the moment, but I would like it to scale to the width of the table at all times.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think to size the background, you should use [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) somewhere in there.

Comment: @GolezTrol Not sure that's supported for Email

Comment: Me neither, and it will depend on the client. It can't hurt to try. And if it doesn't work, I don't think there is a solution. If the client blocks it there is not much you can do.

Comment: Using a background image in an e-mail is bad practice. Some e-mail clients don't even support a static sized background image, even fewer support a responsive one.

Comment: @APAD1 Thanks for the tip, I went for a repeatable pattern to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting background-size:contain; on the element you have the image on.
You will only see it work on smaller screens to begin with such as tablets and smartphones, which at a guess would have support.
Css support seems far better on mobile than on desktop versions of clients...

Comment: Noticed this as well :( I decided to just go for a repeatable pattern instead as I didn't have to worry about figuring out how to make the image resposnive.

Comment: No worries. It's always best to go with a repeatable pattern, but I know from experience, that isn't always possible when designing to someone else's specifications :)

And in reference to @ADAP1 's response, with your use of bulletproof backgrounds, support for 99% of email clients isn't an issue anymore. Could be even better now, as one major client was updated recently to support the hack.

Comment: Outlook mobile app is the big problem now :)  You can kind of make it responsive on everything except that as it doesn't currently support media queries (why would it... it's a mobile app *sigh*)